# new features selection

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, feature-selection, data-mining, feature-engineering

I am in a project in which I have a specific description of a certain binary profile for which I have about 200 positive examples and another 200 negative. This description is given from about 60 features. The objective is to find new features that statistically differentiate the positives from the negatives (that is, for example, that for a new given feature the values for the positives are high and for the negatives low).

How would be able to do that?

Comment: This really depends on what you mean my "statistically differentiate".  If by that you mean you are looking for effects related to increase probability of a positive case, you would likely need some sort of parametric model like a logistic regression.

Comment: what I am looking for is a method to find new features that complete the initial ones and that are able to differentiate the positives from the negatives.